# How to configure Apache Ignite in XML?

Tags: ignite, in-memory

Where can I find documentation for of all the availible configuration properties and how they look in XML? I'm using Ignite C++.

For example, I need to configure memory policies, and I'm not sure how to specify that in XML config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite uses Spring for XML configuration. Spring allows you to construct Java objects from XML: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html

You can figure out the XML by looking at `IgniteConfiguration` class documentation: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/index.html

Comment: thanks exactly what i wanted. Appreciate the edits too.